# How can I modify the #+ and #- readtable macros in Lisp?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sbcl

**Short version:**

I want to change the `#+` and `#-` reader macros to apply to all immediately subsequent tokens starting with `#@`, in addition to the following token. Therefore, the following code...

```
#+somefeature
#@someattribute1
#@someattribute2
(defun ...)
```

...would, in the absence of `somefeature`, result in no code.

---

**Long version:**

I have written my own [readtable](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/v_rdtabl.htm)-macros which apply transformations to subsequent code. For example:

```
#@traced
(defun ...)
```

This yields a function that writes its arguments and return values to a file, for debugging.

This fails, however, when used in conjunction with the `#+` reader macro:

```
#+somefeature
#@traced
(defun ...)
```

In the absence of `somefeature`, the function continues to be defined, albeit without the `#@traced` modification. This is obviously not the desired outcome.

One possible solution would be to use `progn`, as follows:

```
#+somefeature
(progn
  #@traced
  (defun ...))
```

But that's kind of ugly.

I would like to modify the `#+` and `#-` reader macros, such that they may consume more than one token. Something like this:

```
(defun conditional-syntax-reader (stream subchar arg)
  ; If the conditional fails, consume subsequent tokens while they
  ; start with #@, then consume the next token.
)
(setf *readtable* (copy-readtable))
(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\+ #'conditional-syntax-reader)
(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\- #'conditional-syntax-reader)
```

The problem is, I don't know how to "delegate" to the original reader macros; and I don't understand enough about how they were implemented to re-implement them myself in their entirety.

A naive approach would be:

```
(defun consume-tokens-recursively (stream)
  (let ((token (read stream t nil t)))
    (when (string= "#@" (subseq (symbol-string token) 0 2))
      (consume-tokens-recursively stream))))    ; recurse
(defun conditional-syntax-reader (stream subchar arg)
  (unless (member (read stream t nil t) *features*)
    (consume-tokens-recursively stream)))
```

However, I'm given to believe that [this wouldn't be sufficient](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node191.html):

> The #+ syntax operates by first reading the feature specification and then skipping over the form if the feature is false. This skipping of a form is a bit tricky because of the possibility of user-defined macro characters and side effects caused by the #. and #, constructions. It is accomplished by binding the variable *read-suppress* to a non-nil value and then calling the read function.

This seems to imply that I can just `let ((*read-suppress* t))` when using `read` to solve the issue. Is that right?

---

**EDIT 1**

Upon further analysis, it seems the problem is caused by not knowing how many tokens to consume. Consider the following attributes:

- `#@export` expects one argument: the `(defun ...)` to export.
- `#@traced` expects two arguments: the debug level and the `(defun ...)` to trace.

Example:

```
#+somefeature
#@export
#@traced 3
(defun ...)
```

It turns out that `#+` and `#-` *are* capable of suppressing *all* these tokens; but there is a huge problem!

When under a suppressing `#+` or `#-`, ***`(read)` returns `NIL`!***

Example:

```
(defun annotation-syntax-reader (stream subchar arg)
 (case (read stream t nil t)
  ('export
   (let ((defun-form   (read stream t nil t)))))
    ; do something
  ('traced
   (let* ((debug-level (read stream t nil t))
          (defun-form  (read stream t nil t)))))))
    ; do something

(setf *readtable* (copy-readtable))
(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\@ #'annotation-syntax-reader)

#+(or) #@traced 3 (defun ...)
```

The `#@traced` token is being suppressed by the `#+`. In this situation, all the `(read)` calls in `(annotation-syntax-reader)` *consume real tokens but return NIL!*

Therefore, the `traced` token is consumed, but the `case` fails. No additional tokens are thus consumed; and control leaves the scope of the `#+`.

The `(defun ...)` clause is executed as normal, and the function comes into being. Clearly not the desired outcome.

Comment: Why not write a macro, such that (traceing (defun foo ...)) or even (defun-traced  ...) or (with-attributes (:traced) (defun ... ))

Comment: Sure, I could do those things. It's more a case of readability, though. `defun-traced` won't be correctly highlighted in my editor. Nesting `defun`s inside other constructs means that they are no longer at top level; which just looks wrong. Plus - and I may be wrong on this - doesn't lisp have subtle rules about `defun`s being at top level? I remember reading something that said if a `defun` isn't at top level (or inside a `let` or `progn`), it won't be treated the same in some respect...?

Comment: Editor highlighting can be configured. About Toplevel: just let the macro be expanded into top-level code using PROGN.

Comment: Editor highlighting can't always be configured, or can't always be configured *easily*. You make a valid point about macro expansion, though.

Comment: I think the conditionals reader macros **set** the read-suppress variable and the reader macros may use them to be smart and skip some parsing steps; the default reader is smart enough I think to avoid interning symbols, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The standard readtable

Changing the macros for `#+` and `#-` is a bit excessive solution I think, but in any case remember to not actually change the standard readtable (as you did, but its important to repeat in the answer)

> The consequences are undefined if an attempt is made to modify the standard readtable. To achieve the effect of altering or extending standard syntax, a copy of the standard readtable can be created; see the function copy-readtable.

[§2.1.1.2 The Standard Readtable](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/02_aab.htm)

Now, maybe I'm missing something (please give us a hint about how your reader macro is defined if so), but I think it is possible to avoid that and write your custom macros in a way that works for your use case.

#### Reader macro

Let's define a simple macro as follows:

```
CL-USER> (defun my-reader (stream char)
           (declare (ignore char))
           (let ((name (read stream)
                 (form (read stream))
           (unless *read-suppress*
             `(with-decoration ,name ,form)))
MY-READER
```

[**NB:** This was edited to take into account `*read-suppress*`: the code always read two forms, but returns `nil` in case it is being ignored. In the comments you say that you may need to read an indefinite number of forms based on the name of the decoration, but with `*read-suppress*` the recursive calls to `read` return `nil` for symbols, so you don't know which decoration is being applied. In that case it might be better to wrap some arguments in a literal list, or parse the stream manually (`read-char`, etc.). Also, since you are using a dispatching macro, maybe you can add a numerical argument if you want the decoration to be applied to more than one form (`#2@inline`), but that could be a bad idea when later the decorated code is being modified.]

Here the reader does a minimal job, namely build a form that is intended to be macroexpanded later. I don't even need to define `with-decoration` for now, as I'm interested in the read step. The intent is to read the next token (presumably a symbol that indicates what decoration is being applied, and a form to decorate).

I'm binding this macro to a unused character:

```
CL-USER> (set-macro-character #\§ 'my-reader)
T
```

Here when I test the macro it wraps the following form:

```
CL-USER> (read-from-string "§test (defun)")
(WITH-DECORATION TEST (DEFUN))
13 (4 bits, #xD, #o15, #b1101)
```

And here it works with a preceding QUOTE too, the apostrophe reader grabs the next form, which recursively reads two forms:

```
CL-USER> '§test (defun)
(WITH-DECORATION TEST (DEFUN))
```

Likewise, a conditional reader macro will ignore all the next lines:

```
CL-USER> #+(or) t
; No values

CL-USER> #+(or) §test (defun)
; No values

CL-USER> #+(or) §one §two §three (defun)
; No values
```

#### Decoration macro

If you use this syntax, you'll have nested decorated forms:

```
CL-USER> '§one §two (defun test ())
(WITH-DECORATION ONE (WITH-DECORATION TWO (DEFUN TEST ())))
```

With respect to `defun` in toplevel positions, you can arrange for your macros to unwrap the nesting (not completely tested, there might be bugs):

```
(defun unwrap-decorations (form stack)
  (etypecase form
    (cons (destructuring-bind (head . tail) form
            (case head
              (with-decoration (destructuring-bind (token form) tail
                (unwrap-decorations form (cons token stack))))
              (t `(with-decorations ,(reverse stack) ,form)))))))

CL-USER> (unwrap-decorations ** nil)
(WITH-DECORATIONS (ONE TWO) (DEFUN TEST ()))
```

And in turn, `with-decorations` might know about `DEFUN` forms and how to annotate them as necessary.

For the moment, our original macro is only the following (it needs more error checking):

```
(defmacro with-decoration (&whole whole &rest args)
  (unwrap-decorations whole nil))
```

For the sake of our example, let's define a generic annotation mechanism:

```
CL-USER> (defgeneric expand-decoration (type name rest))
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP-USER::EXPAND-DECORATION (0)>
```

It is used in `with-decorations` to dispatch on an appropriate expander for each decoration. Keep in mind that all the efforts here are to keep `defun` in a top-level positions (under a `progn`), a recursive annotation would let evaluation happens (in the case of `defun`, it would result in the name of the function being defined), and the annotation could be done on the result.

The main macro is then here, with a kind of *fold* (reduce) mechanism where the forms are decorated using the resulting expansion so far. This allows for expanders to place code before or after the main form (or do other fancy things):

```
(defmacro with-decorations ((&rest decorations) form)
  (etypecase form
    (cons (destructuring-bind (head . tail) form
            (ecase head
              (defun (destructuring-bind (name args . body) tail
                       `(progn
                          ,@(loop
                              for b = `((defun ,name ,args ,@body)) then forms
                              for d in decorations
                              for forms = (expand-decoration d name b)
                              finally (return forms))))))))))
```

(nb. here above we only care about `defun` but the `loop` should probably be done outside of the dispatching thing, along with a way to indicate to expander methods that a function is being expanded; well, it could be better)

Say, for example, you want to declare a function as `inline`, then the declaration must happen before (so that the compiler can know the source code must be kept):

```
(defmethod expand-decoration ((_ (eql 'inline)) name rest)
  `((declaim (inline ,name)) ,@rest))
```

Likewise, if you want to export the name of the function being defined, you can export it after the function is defined (order is not really important here):

```
(defmethod expand-decoration ((_ (eql 'export)) name rest)
  `(,@rest (export ',name)))
```

The resulting code allows you to have a single `(progn ...)` form with a `defun` in toplevel position:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '§inline §export (defun my-test-fn () "hello"))
(PROGN
 (DECLAIM (INLINE MY-TEST-FN))
 (DEFUN MY-TEST-FN () "hello")
 (EXPORT 'MY-TEST-FN))
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very detailed answer; and it helped me figure out what the problem was. It turns out that `(read stream)` inside `my-reader` consumes real tokens from the input, but *returns `NIL`* (when suppressed by `#+`). This is a major problem, because the number of tokens I need to consume depends on the actual name of the attribute. For example, the `§export` attribute consumes only one token (the `defun` to export), whereas the `§traced` attribute consumes two.

Comment: Desired syntax: `#@traced 1 (defun ...)`. The `1` represents the _debug level_ of the trace.

Comment: With `(read stream)` returning `NIL` (which happens when `#+` or `#-` are suppressing the subsequent input), there is no way to know which attribute we have. And failure to `(read)` the correct number of tokens results in the orphaned tokens being parsed normally, outside of the scope of the `#+`.

Comment: I will add to my question, clarifying this.

Comment: @SodAlmighty Instead make the syntax be `#@(traced 1) <form>`, so there are always exactly two calls to `read`.

Comment: alternatively call read-char on the stream yourself to grab the token, it should work even with read-supress being t

Comment: @coredump Your answer is lovely, but I think you want to handle `*read-suppress*` to make sure that your reader macro returns `nil` in this case:  `my-reader` wants to check for `*read-suppress*` and if so just to `(progn (read stream) (read stream) nil)`

Comment: I guess I didn't understand until _right this minute_ what `*read-suppress*` actually does. I should have paid more attention when reading the docs on it. Anyhow, I tried `(let ((*read-suppress* nil)) (read stream t nil t)))` and that worked perfectly!

Comment: I will accept your answer. Despite not _in and of itself_ solving my root issue, it helped me realise what my issue truly _was_. Thank you.

Comment: @ignisvolens That is actually a really good idea; and one that had not occurred to me. I might do that! Thank you.

Comment: @SodAlmighty: do *not* bind `*read-suppress*` to `nil` if it is not `nil`.  See the notes to [the CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_rd_sup.htm) and in particular 'Programmers and implementations that define additional macro characters are strongly encouraged to make them respect `*read-suppress*` just as standardized macro characters do.'  What you are doing is directly violating that guidance.

Comment: @ignisvolens I'll update the answer, this was done a bit too quickly last night

Comment: @ignisvolens Guidance is there to make you think twice before doing something that may be ill-advised. Doesn't mean you can't do it. In this case, there may be situations that _absolutely require_ the ability to know the name of the token after the `#@`, even given your suggestion about enclosing the arguments in parens (which I have now done). It is not beyond the realm of possibility that an attribute might have to apply to more than one target form, or none.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the [documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_rd_sup.htm) seems to say that `*read-suppress*` exists pretty much _entirely_ to permit `#+` and `#-` to elide code that is not valid in the current lisp dialect. In my case, all I am reading here is a single form consisting of a symbol and maybe some simple literals like numbers or strings. These things would be valid in any lisp dialect you care to name.

Comment: Indeed, the notes at the bottom of that documentation page imply that it is acceptable to read the following object, provided you don't throw a type exception.

Comment: @SodAlmighty: "The standard syntax and its associated reader macros will not construct any new objects (e.g., when reading the representation of a symbol, no symbol will be constructed or interned ... Programmers and implementations that define additional macro characters are strongly encouraged to make them respect `*read-suppress*` just as standardized macro characters do."  But comments are not the place for this discussion. Do what ever you want to do: the standard can't protect you from yourself, any more than I can.